# MacOSX Give alias/symlink label color but not original file

Tags: macos, applescript, label, symlink

Hoi Stackoverflow,

i have a short question. Is it possible to set the label of an alias/symlink to a certain color without effecting other symlinks and the original file?

Lets say if have one main folder and different subgroups. Each subgroups contains symlinks to the files in the main folder.
I want know to color these symlinks according to some variables which is easily done with

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set label index of alias POSIX file \"$1\" to \"$2\""
```

Unfortunately this changes the label index of the main file as well as and the ones from all other symlinks to that particular file.

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: I think you are using Unix non-symbolic links. Using those I have the same problem. Using aliasses created with Finder I don't. Unix symbolic links can't be given a color label.

Comment: yeah i realized that as well. unfortunately our play out software doesnt support apple aliases...